# Ionic, jQuery and websockets

Tags: jquery, websocket, ionic3

I have a web app up and running. It is for a gaming platform, where 1 to 5 player(s) click something, data gets sent to the server and the server sends back data to all the clients. The clients then update their DOM through jQuery.

Now I am developing a mobile app for this platform. The web app uses HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery on the client side, cakePHP and Ratchet for websockets on the server side. For the mobile app, I am using Ionic.

Since I do not want to rewrite all the code of the websocket for node.js, I am not using socket.io on the client side. Rather, I leave the server side websocket code and use the jQuery code from the client of the web app. In Ionic, I pasted it into the ngAfterViewInit() function. Everything works, except I would like to be able to pass variables. For example:

```
ngAfterViewInit()

$(document).ready(function(){

    var host = "quiztime.live"; var port = 8010;
    var socket = 'wss://' + host + '/wss' + port + '/' + port;
    var conn = new WebSocket(socket);

    conn.onopen = function(e) {
        var PLAY = 7;
        var msg = { 'type':PLAY, 'user_id': this.user_id, 'game_id': this.game_id };
        conn.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
    }

});
```

which gives an error because this.user_id and this.game_id are of course not defined, for in the context of conn.onopen() "this" now refers to the websocket, not to the Ionic class.

How can I use variables from my Ionic class within jQuery in the ngAfterViewInit() function?

Or is there a better way altogether to implement this project in Ionic?

Comment: I dont understand why wrap in jquery again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I question the use of jQuery in this case, but you probably want to use ES6 notation to be able to get to the highest `this` reference:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(document).ready(() => {

        var host = "quiztime.live"; var port = 8010;
        var socket = 'wss://' + host + '/wss' + port + '/' + port;
        var conn = new WebSocket(socket);

        conn.onopen = (e) => {
            var PLAY = 7;
            var msg = { 'type':PLAY, 'user_id': this.user_id, 'game_id': this.game_id };
            conn.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason why I use jquery is: there is very much DOM handling going on for every user whenever something gets sent through the websocket and I thought, why not use the (jquery) code that is working so well in the web app? But perhaps there is a better solution. I am new to Ionic. Do you propose another approach?

Comment: It mostly depends on your current experience and project setup to determine the need of jQuery. I used jQuery *a lot* before Angular (2+) and Ionic but, since then, I pretty much don't use it anymore. Angular provides a whole other approach to accessing DOM elements. I suggest you should follow some tutorials on Ionic and Angular to see for yourself if jQuery is still needed in this and your future projects.

Comment: Sounds like you prefer the Angular approach over jquery. Can you please recommend some good tutorials on Angular DOM handling?

Comment: [This](https://www.joshmorony.com/safely-modifying-elements-with-elementref-renderer/) is an approach within Ionic (by Josh Morony). I would recommend taking a look at more of Josh's tutorials. And look at [this one](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02) for using `@ViewChild` and such.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help!